# C array pointer usage clarification

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment

I have a seemingly simple question regarding array pointer in C. I am trying to understand a portion of code written in C, so i can port it to C#. The data types and functions are defined as follows:

```
/* header file */
/* definition of data_t type */
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef uint16_t data_t;

/*  the function the type data_t is used */
#define FOO(d) do {
 d[0] = 1;
 d[1] = 2;
} while (0)

/* source file */
/* the function where FOO is used */
static int BAR(data_t* const data)
{
   FOO(data + 1);
}
```

When calling FOO(..) within BAR(..), what does "data + 1" mean? As i understand, data is an array from type data_t. 
I wasn't able to find an exact example on stackoverflow or else, therefore i am confused about the meaning of it. 
I have three options in my mind how an appropriate assignment in C# could look like:

1. data + 1 -> data[1]
2. data + 1 -> data[0] + 1
3. data + 1 -> new data_t[] (new instance of data_t array at address + 1)

The first option makes sense to me. But when taking a look into the function FOO(..), it makes no sense, because FOO is using "data" like an array.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: `*(data+1)` == `data[1]`. `(data+1)[1]` == `data[2]`. You can use any pointer as array (there is no guarantee this is a valid memory address, however).

Comment: Data is a pointer. By doing `data + 1', you move your pointer to the next element in memory.

Comment: `data` is not an array, but a pointer. Possibly to the first element of a `data_t` array. In C you cannot pass an array as argument, only pointers.

Comment: I'd start by rewriting the macro to a function: `inline void (data_t* data) { d[0]=1; d[1]=2 }` or just drop it entirely. The presence of that icky macro plus the pointless declaration `data_t* const` suggests that the person who wrote the code were fond of "lets make the code as complex as possible by using various obscure tricks" but in reality doesn't quite know what they are doing.

Comment: the macro is in fact invalid (need to use `\ ` for multi-line macro), and its use as shown will cause an error (`data + 1[0]` is not valid C)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Nicely spotted. Turns out the whole code is nonsense then. So maybe this was an artificial example and not the actual code?

Comment: I think the last comment from user3714840 clarifies it for me. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Lundin thanks for your comments. I just wanted to understand the meaning of this semantics, so I know what to do, when rewriting it in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C pointers and arrays are usually interchangeable.

`data_t*` is equivalent to `data_t[]` in most cases, and the use of the array notation is used to simplify the dereferencing of the pointers for assignment.

```
data[0] = 1;
data[1] = 2;
```

can be replaced with

```
*(data) = 1;
*(data+1) = 2;
```

It really is just semantics, although the use of the macro is ugly.  Either way you can access out of range memory locations and cause trouble when accessing memory which is unassigned.

### Update:

```
*(data+1) != data + 1
```

`data + 1` - Memory location at the pointer data + 1 * (size of data type of the pointer).  In other words, it is one unit over from the position of data.

`*(data + 1)` - Value at memory location of said data type.

Comment: Thanks for this input. But just because it's C, i want to state it more precisely. Is *(data + 1) = data + 1?

Comment: It's always interesting to see an accepted answer with 0 upvotes... how can an answer solve the OP's problem but at the same time not be useful?

Comment: @Michael I updated the answer.  Basically `*(data+1)` does not equal `data + 1`

Answer (score 2):

In this context:

```
data + 1
```

Means:

```
data + sizeof(data_t);
```

Because `data` is a pointer of type `data_t` pointer arithmetic is applied so that `+ 1` results in `sizeof(data_t)` bytes further than `data`.

So your first assumption is correct.